# How do I make it look like the picture in Lua

Tags: lua

This is my code

```
local level = 5 
for i = 1, level do 
 local text = "" 
 for j = 1, i do 
  text = text.."" 
 end 
 for j = 1, level-i, 1 do 
  text = text.." " 
 end 
 for j = 1+level, level+(level-i) do 
  text = text.." " 
 end 
 for j = 1, level + i-level do
  text = text.."" 
 end 
 print(text) 
end
```

I want the result to be similar to the one in the picture.

[image]

Comment: The last line has 10 characters, but I only need 9 characters.

Comment: yup, maybe you need to print 1 character less in the last line

Comment: I tried using a star first and changing it to a number later.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what your code looks like with proper formatting.

```
local level = 5
for i = 1, level do
    local text = ""
    for j = 1, i do
        text = text..""
    end
    for j = 1, level-i, 1 do
        text = text.." "
    end
    for j = 1+level, level+(level-i) do
        text = text.." "
    end
    for j = 1, level + i-level do
        text = text..""
    end
    print(text)
end
```

Your current code prints... well... an empty string. You haven't yet added the characters it's to display to be on par with the image.

The amount of characters per row is 9. So you ideally need 9 characters per row. You will also be incrementing the number once per row. The amount of characters per row also increases by 2; one on each side.

We can use the `string.rep(string, number)` function to duplicate a 'string' 'number' times. You can feed in your current level into that so it generates 1 2 or 3 depending on the line the number of times. Then you have whitespace to worry about. You can use `string.rep` again along with a bit of distance math to calculate the amount of whitespace you need from what you take up. Then finally throw everything together concatenated trailing with the first string and print.

```
local levels = 5
local columns = 9
for i=1, levels do
    local str = string.rep(i, i)
    local padding = columns - (#str * 2) + 1
    print(str .. string.rep(" ", padding) .. str)
end
```